# XNA 4 / Monogame 3d tunnel collision

Tags: xna

I am trying to collide an aircraft with a FBX tunnel model. I don't know how to create multiple bounding boxes for a tunnel. The tunnel is contains a single mesh. I tried using the triangle picking sample here http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/picking_triangle
I also created a bounding sphere around the tunnel to be able to detect if the aircraft is inside the tunnel. If the ship is inside the tunnel then I check the triangle & ray intersection. I also detect the intersection. I tried changing the rotation and position of the ship when intersection occurred but although I can detect the intersection ship passes through the tunnel surface mostly and my rotation doesn't work well.

I also tried to calculate ray & plane (here it is triangle) reflection as below:

```
            if (intersection < 0.4f)
            {
                Plane pickedTriangle = new Plane(vertex1, vertex2, vertex3);
                Vector3 reflectionVector = Vector3.Reflect(direction, pickedTriangle.Normal);
                newPosition = modelPosition + direction * gameSpeed * reflectionVector;
                newDirection = reflectionVector;
                tIntersected = true;
            }
```

As I see newPosition isn't calculated correctly.

My question is; how can I calculate a new position after a ray & plane intersection.

I think this causes the ship sometimes pass the tunnel surface sometimes.
If there is a better way to detect and calculate tunnel collision I'll appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: Just a notice.. I changed the if (intersection < 0.4f) to if (intersection < 12.0f), where intersection is the distance of the ray to the plane, collision and ship movement behaviour works well.. but there is still a problem when colliding to opposite face of the tunnel. Currently left side collision works well..